# How to solve this ANT issue?

Tags: ant, build

```
<loadfile property="UIfiles" srcfile="updated.txt">         
                <filterchain>          
                    <linecontainsregexp>             
                         <regexp pattern="ui/dev/"/>           
                    </linecontainsregexp>         
                </filterchain>      
</loadfile>       
<echo file="Filelist.txt" append="true">${UIfiles}</echo>
```

> I have the above code in build.xml file. updated.txt will contain some text like Projects/accounts/spec/ui/dev/dpdl/abc.xml. If this statement is present in the file, then the above code works as expected. If there is no match for regex "ui/dev" in updated.txt, ideally the value of UIfiles should be empty and should not write anything to Filelist.txt. But in my case "${UIfiles}" is getting appended in Filelist.txt. Please suggest how to avoid this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works as expected. ${...} is the syntax for your property when not set, because
your file doesn't contain a line matching the regexp.

You need some if isset condition, with Ant 1.9.3 and [new if unless feature](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) :

```
<project 
  xmlns:if="ant:if"
  xmlns:unless="ant:unless"
>

<loadfile property="UIfiles" srcfile="updated.txt">         
 <filterchain>          
  <linecontainsregexp>             
   <regexp pattern="ui/dev/"/>           
  </linecontainsregexp>         
 </filterchain>      
</loadfile>       

<echo file="Filelist.txt" append="true">${UIfiles} if:set="UIfiles"</echo> 

</project>
```

otherwise for older Ant versions use:

```
<project>

<target name="checkfile">
<loadfile property="UIfiles" srcfile="updated.txt">         
 <filterchain>          
  <linecontainsregexp>             
   <regexp pattern="ui/dev/"/>           
  </linecontainsregexp>         
 </filterchain>      
</loadfile>
</target>

<target name="appendfilelist" depends="checkfile" if="UIfiles">
 <echo file="Filelist.txt" append="true">${UIfiles}</echo> 
</target>

<project>
```

Comment: how does appendfilelist target get called? my set of statements are already inside a target "checkoutspec".

Comment: Normally the workflow in ant script is set up via dependency chain, means several targets with dependencies on other targets. Personally i often use some main target like <target name="main" depends="target1,target2,..."/> to build up a dependency chain and use that main target as default target in my ant script, f.e. <project name="foobar" xmlns:fl="..." default="main">